# Angular Reactive Form value doesn't work properly?

Tags: angular, typescript

I've created Angular Reactive Form with boolean values of controls. I need get value from slide-toggle control and resolve condition. It looks very simply but in my code result is always false.

```
createForm() {
        this.threatForm = this.fb.group({
        threatId: 0,
        name: ['', [Validators.required]],
        category: [1, [Validators.required]],
        description: [''],
        internalExternal: [1, [Validators.required]],
        securitySafety: [3, [Validators.required]],
        avoidRisk: [],
        shareRisk: [],
        reduceRisk: [],
        acceptRisk: [],
        confidenciality: [false],
        integrity: [false],
        availability: [false],
        authenticity: [false],
    })
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.onGetThreatsCategory();

    if (this.threatForm.value.avoidRisk === true) {
        console.log("Risk value: TRUE")
    }

    else {
        console.log("Risk value: FALSE")
    }
}
```

When I print value in HTML I'm getting good result,

```
  AvoidRisk: {{ this.threatForm.controls.avoidRisk.value | json }}
```

but in TypeScript value is FALSE each time.

Comment: hard to tell without the markup, but is the AvoidRisk value a string? `if (this.threatForm.value.avoidRisk === 'true')`

Comment: I was trying with quotes, nothing happening..

Comment: Well I don't see anywhere that you are setting value to that form control, so how can it be `true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to check the value in your `ngOnInit` method, but you are initializing your form control for `avoidRisk` to a falsy value. Additionally, you are not building the form before you check the value of the specific control, so you will always get false.

First, you will need to give `avoidRisk` a default value of true (assuming that you want it to be true in the `OnInit` lifecycle hook, as your example shows):

```
createForm() {
  this.threatForm = this.fb.group({
    threatId: 0,
    name: ['', [Validators.required]],
    category: [1, [Validators.required]],
    description: [''],
    internalExternal: [1, [Validators.required]],
    securitySafety: [3, [Validators.required]],
    avoidRisk: [true], // give it the initial value of true
    shareRisk: [],
    reduceRisk: [],
    acceptRisk: [],
    confidenciality: [false],
    integrity: [false],
    availability: [false],
    authenticity: [false],
  })
}
```

Then in your `ngOnInit` method, create the form before you check for the value of it's controls. Now you can subscribe to the [`valueChanges`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#valueChanges) property on your form control, which will return an `Observable` of it's value.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.createForm(); // create the form

  /* subscribe to your form control's value */
  this.threatForm.get('avoidRisk').valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
    if (this.threatForm.get('avoidRisk').value === true) {
      console.log('Risk value: TRUE');
    } else {
      console.log('Risk value: FALSE');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: My default value for avoidRisk needs to be "false" but it does not metter it can be true. I want only check which value user selected for this field and call if condition..I made last chagnes with adding createForm() in ngOnInit() method and the same thing. Problem is what I'm always getting value from createForm() method, but I want value from form input. If I set default value on true my result is true, if I set false result is false. I can not get value from control in typesricpt in html I can see good result..

Comment: Got it -- updated my answer to show the behavior you are after.

Comment: It's working....Thank you @vincecampale...How much code for one boolean condition. I need apply for rest of controls...Thanks man +1 :-)

Comment: Happy to help :) Consider "accepting" the answer by clicking the check mark so others know that your question has been answered. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

To get value from a form control, `this.threatForm.get('avoidRisk').value`, you can use this as,

```
if (this.threatForm.get('avoidRisk').value === true) { ... } else { ... }
```

and in html,

```
{{threatForm.get('avoidRisk').value}}
```

Comment: I've changed this and I got other error: "(TS) Objesct is possibily null".

Comment: I've added this Non-null assertion operator and fix error but result is same. It's always FALSE..                                                                                             `if (this.threatForm.get('avoidRisk')!.value === true)`

Comment: In createForm  function change like this, avoidRisk: [''] and check if (this.threatForm.get('avoidRisk').value) { ... } else { ... }

Comment: I did it but the same thing...return FALSE again each time.